# how to use FormView control on windows Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I need to use FormView control on windows forms I have tried it but not helping as it helps in asp.net (specially for insert,update,delete operations) do you have any idea? please help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: _I have tried it but.._ Show what you tried..

Comment: you probably wanna see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/555193/145682

Comment: @deostroll i had visited this link before but its not the perfect solution. It only shows data on form with various controls like gridview,textboxes etc. but cannot insert update delete simply as in ASP.net

Comment: since web applications are stateless you need patterns of insert, update, delete _appearing as separate commands_ to the application which is hosted on a web server. In a windows applications, its all state-ful. So a group of control bound to a binding source, will kind of link to the underlying datatable (or datasource) almost instantaneously. Hence you can call something like a `SqlDataAdapter.Update()` passing the datatable...(provided you take care of providing the update, insert, & delete commands appropriately)